# Cannot produce slide with regression equation

Tags: beamer, equations

I've started using beamer to make slides. However, I cannot produce a slide with a regression equation on it (although it worked with \documentclass{article} ):

```
\[ Y_{ht} = \alpha + \beta K_{ht} + \gamma_{h} \]
```

Since I installed \usepackage{amsmath}, I used the math mode:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
Y_{ht} = \alpha + \beta K_{ht} + \gamma_{h}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I could not generate the pdf. Also, if I don't want to use the math mode, how should I write my equation? This might be a simple problem but it took me hours and I still don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your minimal document compiles without problem.

Comment: Off-topic: `beamer` load `amsmath`, so you not need to load it again.

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ and when it was last updated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean with ‘math mode’? All maths formulæ are typed in math mode.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input! In MS Windows Control Panel, I realized I had **2 versions of MikTex on my computer** so I removed one of them. The code works now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!